# Input type=file alternative to be used in Google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Google chrome extension where user uploads a file manually. I have created a  file type input in popup.html and tried to read the file. But that is not working as that is bug in Google chrome..

Please someone suggest me if there is any other work around. I [found](http://codereview.chromium.org/3209002) this but I am unable to proceed cause I could not understand their terminology.

Thanks

Comment: Provide more details. What's not working?

Comment: @BorisSmus http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=98920 Please have a look at this... That is the problem

Comment: There's no good workaround I know of. Prompt for files from an options page?

Comment: @BorisSmus Yes... Anyway I have done this in different approach and it is working fine... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any workaround to solve this problem and solved it in another way..Here I am posting the code which I have used

First in Popup Page :

```
 chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
      chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {
                'action': 'inject'
      });
 });
```

In Content Script :

```
 chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function ListeningMethod(request, sender,callback)
 {
switch(request.action)
{
    case "inject":
            if($('body').find('#TesterItems').size() < 1)
            {
                $('body').prepend("<div id='TesterItems'><center><input type='file' id='xfilex'></center></div>");
            }
            else
            {
                $('#TesterItems').html("<center><input type='file' id='xfilex'></center>");
                $('#TesterItems').slideToggle('slow');
            }
    break;

 }
});
$('#xfilex').live('change',function()
{
var file = document.getElementById('xfilex').files[0];
if(file)
{
    var reader;
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    reader.onload = loaded;
}
});

function loaded(evt)
{
var fileString = evt.target.result;
var str = fileString;
if(str.length > 0 )
{
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "passThisXML", key: str}, function(response) {
        $('#TesterItems').html('<center><span style="padding:3px">Successfully loaded XML.</span></center>');
        $('#TesterItems').slideToggle('slow');
        var Dat = response.data;
    });
}
 }
```